# MySQL - get a column showing COUNT() from an associated table on each row

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a database in MySQL (5.5.60-MariaDB).

I'm doing a `SELECT` query to get rows from a table called `revision_filters` followed by various `INNER JOIN`'s to get associated data. The query looks as follows and executes correctly:

```
SELECT RevisionFilters.id      AS `RevisionFilters__id`,
       RevisionFilters.date    AS `RevisionFilters__date`,
       RevisionFilters.comment AS `RevisionFilters__comment`,
       filters.label           AS `Filters__label`,
       filters.anchor          AS `Filters__anchor`,
       groups.label            AS `Groups__label`
FROM   revision_filters RevisionFilters
       INNER JOIN dev_hub_subdb.filters Filters
               ON filters.id = ( RevisionFilters.filter_id )
       INNER JOIN dev_hub_subdb.groups Groups
               ON groups.id = ( filters.group_id )
       INNER JOIN dev_hub_subdb.regulations Regulations
               ON regulations.id = ( groups.regulation_id )
```

There is a table called `revision_filters_substances`. The structure of the table is as follows. In this instance `revision_filter_id` is a foreign key that relates to `revision_filters.id`.

```
mysql> describe revision_filters_substances;
+--------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| revision_filter_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| substance_id       | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What I want to do is adapt my `SELECT` query so that on each row returned I can get a `COUNT` of the number of rows in `revision_filters_substances` that correspond to the rows in the `SELECT` query for `revision_filters`.

In some instances, it's possible that there are no rows in `revision_filters_substances` corresponding to a particular `revision_filters.id` and in this case I need the count to return 0.

I've read https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133384/counting-rows-from-a-subquery

But I can't see how to adapt this to my query.

It says on the linked article

> The subquery should immediately follow the FROM keyword.

So I've tried doing this immediately following `FROM revision_filters RevisionFilters` in the query I have already:

```
, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM revision_filters_substances WHERE id = revision_filters.id) AS count_substances
```

But this errors:

> Unknown column 'revision_filters.id' in 'where clause'

Please can someone advise if this is possible? I don't see how to specify 0 if there are no corresponding rows either, so also need advice on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have aliased the `revision_filters` table to `RevisionFilters`. Use `RevisionFilters.id` instead in the `where` clause of the [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html).

Also, to handle "no rows", current subquery will return `NULL`; you would have to use [`Coalesce(..)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) around it to return 0.

```
SELECT .... , 
       COALESCE(SELECT COUNT(id) 
                FROM revision_filters_substances 
                WHERE id = RevisionFilters.id, 0) AS count_substances 
.... /* your rest of the query here (FROM, WHERE clauses etc) */
```

Comment: Thank you. It errors `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '((SELECT COUNT(id) 
                 FROM revision_filters_substances 
         ' at line 1`

Comment: @Andy I have removed additional parentheses around the `select` subquery. Please try again; also this particular subquery is used inside the `select` clause; not the `from` clause. So please ensure that.

Comment: It's still giving an error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT COUNT(id) 
                FROM revision_filters_substances `. I've used an editor to make sure the parentheses match up correctly and they do

Comment: @Andy please give the complete query you are using. If possible, setup a fiddle at: db-fiddle.com

Comment: @Andy in my earlier comment, I had mentioned that the subquery should be in the main `SELECT` clause, not the `FROM` clause. Anyways, here is the updated fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aXV6Rkwsa6Eb3nCMEqkPkK/1 Please check that, and let me know

Comment: Many thanks, that works as expected. Had to also change the `where` condition otherwise it always returned a count of 1! `WHERE revision_filter_id = RevisionFilters.id), 0)` But that's specific to the application not this question. Thanks again.